# Kubernetes + Calico + CRIO - Pod access issue

Tags: iptables, kubernetes, calico

I have a Kubernetes cluster (bare metal) with one control-plane and 10 nodes. All the worker nodes are the same: same OS, same kube / crio / iptables / ufw versions.

I'm using Calico, the pod CIDR & service CIDR are fine.

I have added two more nodes, one is working perfectly fine, the other one has a weird issue: when I'm running a pod on it and trying to do a nslookup, it can reach the Coredns service. BUT on some endpoints it timed out and on some others it works.

Basically if Coredns is running on node 1,2,3,4,5. I will be able to reach 1, 2 and 3 but not 4 and 5. This will always be consistent.

I'm using UFW as a firewall on the host. There is no restriction between the nodes (UFW allows access in and out between each node).

I'm trying to get my head around this issue for two days now and I can't seem to understand what's the issue.

Did anyone run into a similar issue in the past? Does someone have an idea (even the teeny-tiny one)?

### Edit based on Jen Luther Thomas's answer

Thanks for your answer.

I did everything. Here are the DNS packets that are captured by TCPdump as seen in Wireshark.

When I'm trying to reach a reachable node:

[nslookup google.com between my faulty node and one I can reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dj1V.png)

When I'm trying to reach a unreachable node:

[nslookup google.com between my faulty node and one I cannot reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99FSd.png)

We see that I can't get an answer. I don't even have a timeout in the coredns logs.

If I fire up a HTTP server on the host of one of my unreachable nodes, I can reach the server from my faulty node, so I know my firewall rules don't block the communication between the hosts. Disabling UFW does not change anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,

Corentin

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already tried turning the faulty nodes off and on again, I would try that first.

If the behaviour is the same then:

- Try restarting or iptables -F to make sure there is no lingering iptables rules blocking anything.
- Check coredns logs to see if there is a timeout or not
- If there is no log then do a tcpdump on the faulty node and make sure you can see the dns packet

UFW is a bit redundant so you could disable it and use [host endpoint policies](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/reference/resources/hostendpoint).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've edited my question to add some new results

Comment: We know the coredns file is working on the faulty node, but it looks like forwarding to resolve.conf isn't working.

Do you know what IP address 192.168.66.107 is? For some reason, DNS requests on the faulty node are going there. 

It might be a problem with your encapsulation or overlay network. Do these commands give you an output?

```cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward```
```lsmod | grep br_netfilter```
```lsmod | grep overlay```

Comment: 192.168.66.107 is the IP address of a CoreDNS pod running on another node in the cluster (which is unreachable). The same goes for 192.168.96.44 but this pod is located on a node that is reachable. ip_forward gives 1, br_netfilter & overlay are both loaded (br_netfilter           32768  0 bridge                311296  1 br_netfilter AND overlay               163840  9). What puzzles me is the fact that I can reach some nodes but not others. If I had a faulty configuration on the faulty node, I would not be able to reach the entire cluster, right?

Comment: Run a Pod in your nodes  (both faulty, and the one that works)
Do a traceroute or tracepath

I suggest  `kubectl run tmp-shell --rm -i --tty --image nicolaka/netshoot` 
This seems like a networking issue, maybe ufw or something else is blocking encapsulation.

What is the result of these 
`kubectl get installation -o yaml`
`kubectl get nodes -o wide`

`ip route` <- do this on the faulty node

`ss -lntap` <- do this on the faulty node and where coredns is scheduled.